# Jquery 1.7 and IE8 compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

is Jquery 1.7 actually compatible with the IE8.

My code is working fine with Jquery 1.5.x but not with 1.7
Using the developer tools console, I see javascript error "Syntax error" pointing to a line 
that should not give any problem at all...

```
  <title>YourSingapore.com - Search results</title>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you post the exact code or site url? The question seems a little vague. But yes, JQuery 1.7 is completely compatible with IE8.

Comment: There were a lot of major things that changed between 1.5 and 1.6, 1.6 to 1.7 was minor in that department. Big one is prop() and attr().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's compatible with IE8, It must be something else causing the errors.
(Definitely not the `<title>`)

The were "breaking" changes from `JQuery` 1.5 to 1.7, It's probably it.

The supported browsers versions are: **IE 6.0+**, FF 3.6+, Safari 5.0+, Opera, Chrome